# How to print the mysql result using form form which is readonly

Tags: php, mysql, forms

the output didt display on the readonly form

How to print the sql result to the form which is readonly

Provide html code and action.php code. I have try to use &result on readonly form value

---

```
<body>
   <form action = "action.php" method="post" >
      input: <input type="text" name="v_id" />
      <input type="submit" />

</body>
   <?php
      $dbhost = 'localhost';
      $dbuser = 'root';
      $dbpass = 'password';
      $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
      if (!$conn) {
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
      mysql_select_db('transport_fyp207');
      $id = $_POST['v_id'];
      $sql = "SELECT v_price " .
              "FROM vehicle  " .
              "WHERE v_id = $id";
      $result = mysql_query($sql);
   ?>
<body>
   <label for="textfield">output:</label>
   <input name="textfield" 
          type="text" 
          id="textfield" 
          readonly="readonly" 
          value = "<?php $result ?>">
</body>
```

Comment: read more about how to fetch results [php.net](http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot the "echo" and btw you could have the same result with less typing:

```
<label>
  output:
  <input type="text" readonly value="<?php echo $result ?>">
</label>
```

EDIT: as fred -ii- pointed out, this will only work if $result was set. If you want to display something in case of request failure, simply set $result to a default value, something like:

```
<?php echo $result ? $result : "undefined"; ?>
```

And also your sql query is incomplete. Read the PHP manual and see how it's done.

Comment: Yes, the OP left out the `echo`. However, this will only echo IF there are any results from the query. @Gopal